# rails with growl gem error Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - send(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, growl, connection-refused

I am using ruby on rails in OSX 10.10.4, and

each time a run:

```
bundle exec foreman start
```

or

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

or

```
rails s
```

rails gives me this error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - send(2)
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ruby-growl-4.1/lib/ruby-growl/udp.rb:166:in `send'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ruby-growl-4.1/lib/ruby-growl/udp.rb:166:in `send'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ruby-growl-4.1/lib/ruby-growl/udp.rb:151:in `notify'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ruby-growl-4.1/lib/ruby-growl.rb:325:in `notify_udp'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ruby-growl-4.1/lib/ruby-growl.rb:292:in `notify'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/uniform_notifier-1.8.0/lib/uniform_notifier/growl.rb:65:in `notify'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/uniform_notifier-1.8.0/lib/uniform_notifier/growl.rb:33:in `setup_connection_growl'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/uniform_notifier-1.8.0/lib/uniform_notifier/growl.rb:10:in `setup_connection'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/uniform_notifier-1.8.0/lib/uniform_notifier.rb:28:in `growl='
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bullet-4.14.4/lib/bullet.rb:32:in `growl='
~cube/config/environments/development.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
~cube/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've installed Growl 2.1.3 and some times it solves the problem, but ruby sends this error :

```
MacBook:cube ~$ bundle exec foreman start
22:09:30 web.1  | started with pid 867
22:09:31 web.1  | I, [2015-07-11T22:09:31.934069 #867]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
22:09:47 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:47.496864 #867] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
22:09:47 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:47.496979 #867] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)
22:09:47 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:47.999011 #867] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
22:09:47 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:47.999143 #867] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (3 tries left)
22:09:48 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:48.501288 #867] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
22:09:48 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:48.501420 #867] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (2 tries left)
22:09:49 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:49.003666 #867] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
22:09:49 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:49.003800 #867] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (1 tries left)
22:09:49 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:49.504775 #867] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
22:09:49 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:49.504953 #867] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (0 tries left)
22:09:50 web.1  | E, [2015-07-11T22:09:50.007006 #867] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
22:09:50 web.1  | /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:185:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:185:in `new_tcp_server'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:165:in `bind_listen'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:242:in `listen'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `each'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `bind_new_listeners!'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:138:in `start'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
22:09:50 web.1  |   from /~.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
22:09:50 web.1  | exited with code 1
22:09:50 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Could some one give me a hint to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have dependent system libraries that require by ruby-growl?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: ruby-growl is a wrapper, make sure you have growl and libraries installed in the OSX (http://growl.info/downloads)

Comment: errors are happening because you are trying to run Rails but having run it already

Comment: it seems that if I use the growl app it solves the problem. Thus this means I have to use growl each time I run the rails server? because I don't use growl at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily take ruby-growl gem out of Gemfile. If it is not in use, just get rid of extra dependency.